# How to recover a window of firefox?

Tags: firefox, data-recovery, history

By mistake, I have closed a window of firefox with more than 100 tabs opened; I stopped the firefox proccess and restart the program, but it only recovers the others windows, not the one I close (guess thats how it should be); try using *Undo close-tab* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)  but it only recovers the tabs in the active window.
And *Undo close-window* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

I know the tabs must be in the history, but how to track all of the closed window?

Comment: They may or may not be in History, depending on settings.

Comment: Ctrl/Z would probably have done it if you hadn't Quit the app.

Comment: Ill have it in account, there were some addon managing the session but it seems it  has been discontinued,